# host 'X' Blocked because of many connection errors

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

Hi I am Using Java with MySql . I have taken some x hosting service,in that i have deployed my java .war file it is worked  some days ,since 2 days i am getting some error that is

> java.sql.SQLException: null, message from server: "Host 'X host' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'".

I used normal database connection as well as connection pooling.

My code is :

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://IP Address:3306/DBName?user=xxxxx&password=YYYYYYY");
```

..

Please Give a solution ..

Comment: You have to size your poolmanager correctly. Be sure that JDBC connections are correctly closed.

Answer (score 6):

Unblocking the host with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts' 
Or Increasing the max_connect_errors parameter will solve the problem .

server startup:

```
shell> mysqld_safe --max_connect_errors=10000 &
```

Runtime:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL max_connect_errors=10000;
```

But the cause for connection error should be identified.
It Can be Identified by
 * Checking MySQL.err log file
 * Checking TCP/IP connection parameters in the host

Reference:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blocked-host.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connect_errors

Answer (score 1):

To recover the system you might have to restart the mysql server.

```
$ sudo service mysql restart
```

To stop happening this again, Before restarting increase below values,

```
$ mysql> SET GLOBAL max_connections = 500;
$ mysql> SET GLOBAL max_connect_errors=10000;
```

To see the current value please go through the `my.cnf`

```
$ vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Hope this helps!